# How to preserve space an tabulation characters in C# code-behind

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, text, space

I am currently trying to code a Xamarin app that gives the guitar chords of a song above its lyrics, like we can see in guitar tabs sites.

To do this, I am using a List with Song is a class containing the Title of the song, the Singer and the Lyrics (with the chords in it) and everything about that list is written in the C# code-behind.

The problem is that when you write chords with lyrics like I am doing, the chords must be placed exactly above the part of the lyrics where they are played, and aven if I try to write this correctly in my code with spaces and tabulations, the output on the screen isn't the same as in the code.

For example, in C# code-behind I have:

```
"C                                         B\n" +
"Yesterday all my trouble seemed so far away\n"
```

but when it shows on the screen it is misplaced like :

```
C                      B
Yesterday all my trouble seemed so far away
```

So to resume I am searching for a way to preserve the numbers of space characters in a string block in a C# file.

Comment: you need to use a monospaced font - ie, one where every character takes the same horizontal space.  Most fonts are proportional, where some characters are wider than others.